# How to tell sudo to repeat lecture once?

Tags: sudo, users

I'm letting one of my coding buddies have root access to my Raspberry Pi, and as I was getting everything set up, I tested sudo as him.

It gave me "the speech":

> We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
>   Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
>
> #1) Respect the privacy of others.
>      #2) Think before you type.
>      #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

What I'm wondering is how to tell sudo to repeat that once. I can't find where it stores the "warned users" list, and I don't want to go overkill and tell it to give The Speech  every time.

Comment: In Super User, with an accepted answer: [Keeping the fancy sudo warning forever](http://superuser.com/q/500119/84988) (2012-11-05).

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to restore the "seen lecture" status by removing the user's sudo ticket directory, which is probably under `/var/run/sudo`.

Comment: +1 On my Debian, it's under `/var/lib/sudo`

Comment: Nope, nothing. `find /var | grep -i sudo` only returns `/var/db/sudo`, an empty directory, even when run as root. (Well, there is some stuff in `/var/lib/pacman/local`, but upon inspection it seems to be all stuff related to the Pacman cache.)

Comment: It's possible that it's not under `/var`. Try looking at the whole filesystem.

Comment: @GregHewgill Nope, can't find anything good. Did I miss it? http://pastebin.com/dSVFfwYq

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude Since you mention Pacman, are you using Arch Linux? Try `/var/db/sudo/lectured`, which should contain empty files named after users who have received the lecture. Delete the appropriate file from in there.